# What's the control used in Kindle for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7, kindle

I was wondering what kind of control Amazon has used to display text in their application for Windows Phone 7 ? It must be some kind of custom ones because if I remember correctly there's not support for FlowDocument, Run etc in WP7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Run>` is supported on WindowsPhone7 - e.g. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wpf/thread/ca27556a-a33b-4d4e-82b4-a0ed8596d6a1 - you can see Run used in lots of apps - e.g. the official Twitter app.

This question - [Programmatically determining max fit in textbox (WP7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130710/programmatically-detemining-max-fit-in-textbox-wp7) - analyses the Kindle UI control a little bit - it leads me to think that Amazon are using a TextBlock control for the main page, and are doing some manual calculations to work out how many words are on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Kindle ebooks are primarily HTML (output of conversion from [multiple formats](http://forums.kindledirectpublishing.com/kdpforums/entry.jspa?externalID=21&categoryID=29)), so it would be some kind of WebBrower control.

Comment: The Kindle app on the phone definitely doesn't use a WebBrowser control. Sorry. Some of the tell tale signs of a WBC (such as behaviour you can't override) just aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

They haven't detailed this publicly.

I strongly suspect that they have their own controls to wrap a canvas which they dynamically populate with the text and then animate with their own manipulation code.