# Book Reading Experience in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, textblock

I am trying to simulate the experience of reading a book in WP7. I basically have text I need to display in a textblock, enough to fill the page and allow the user to flip to the next page by swiping the finger across the screen.
I am running into a few issues and I'd like to see if anyone has come across this or has a better idea:

- the text I have is much longer than what I can fit on a single page, so I need to put only enough text in the textblock, font size and style are variable so I cannot build fixed pages. Any idea on how to truncate the text at the right length? Everything I could come up with is fairly computational intensive, e.g. add words and measure the textblock until it exceeds a preset size, then paint it
- wp7 textblock lacks support for text justification, so I was wondering if anybody came across good WPF/SL/WP7 techniques for justifying text with variable char width

right now I am looking into having a series of textblocks, one line tall, one after the other in a stackpanel, enough to fill the screen and individually justified, hopefully not too resource intensive.

I will let you know what I find.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be quite a common question.

I recommend:

- Take a look at the Kindle app - it's free and Amazon have built a good app
- Here's some analysis of how Kindle might work - [What's the control used in Kindle for Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267543/whats-the-control-used-in-kindle-for-windows-phone-7) and [Programmatically determining max fit in textbox (WP7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130710/programmatically-detemining-max-fit-in-textbox-wp7)

On your proposal, I think using multiple `<Run>`s inside a single multiline `<TextBlock>` is pretty much the same resource usage as putting multiple lines on a single page - so your approach should be OK.

Comment: Got it. I went with the `Run` approach and was able to have it pretty much working in a couple of hours. The tricky part is keeping track of the different text pointers when moving back and forth. +/-1 make all the difference in the world! :-) If people are interested I can offer more detail. I'll post a sample to my blog when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination - Stuart has **very** nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130710/programmatically-detemining-max-fit-in-textbox-wp7). Solution seems to be in **in-code textblock for measuring**.

Justification - I didn't care about it, so nothing on that part.