# Scrollable textblock in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to **create a scrollable text block**.
But it dont seem to works.
How should i go about doing it?
Below is my code:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Height="517" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,16,0,0" Name="textBlockRules" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="414" FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap" /></ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What's not working? That code looks fine to me. Add some text and try scrolling.

Comment: Try giving your `ScrollViewer` a height value.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you didn't mention explicitly, I'm guessing that your aim is to show some large text without getting chopped.

For such a requirement there are helpful threads on stackoverflow:
1. [Need to show large amount of text on windows phone 7 screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442288/need-to-show-large-amount-of-text-on-windows-phone-7-screen)
2. [Programmatically determining max fit in textbox (WP7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130710/programmatically-detemining-max-fit-in-textbox-wp7)

On the other hand, if all you want is have text blocks in a sequence, you can use a ListBox that is databound to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the maximum height of the ScrollViewer and could set the Visibility for the Scrollbars to Auto.

Here is the example from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx):

```
<ScrollViewer Height="200" Width="200" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Canvas.Top="60" Canvas.Left="340">
<TextBlock Width="300" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Text="I am the very model of a modern Major-General, I've information vegetable, animal, and mineral, I know the kings of England, and I quote the fights historical, From Marathon to Waterloo, in order categorical; I'm very well acquainted, too, with matters mathematical, I understand equations, both the simple and quadratical, About binomial theorem I'm teeming with a lot o' news, With many cheerful facts about the square of the hypotenuse." />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set scrollviewerHorizontalBar to visibal, make textbok stretch and make sure your text is long enough, something like this:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="Scroller">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="100" Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some really long text that should probably wordwrap when you resize the window." />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You should set the maximum height of the ScrollViewer.